# MyUpdatePanel.Update() in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to convert my existing ASP.NET application to [MVC 3 Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_View_Engine). I use a lot of updatepanels, and I do conditional updates at the code behind using `MyUpdatePanel.Update()`.

I am not finding this functionality with MVC 3. I can see a lot of blogposts talking about jQuery and how to use it to achieve the same, but I want to render other partialviews from my action conditionally. Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: There is no code-behind in ASP.NET MVC. I can recommend the [ASP.NET MVC tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc), especially the introduction, to help you convert your web site.

Answer (score 0):

The way you'd work with Ajax in ASP.NET MVC is completely different from the ASP.NET way (i.e., Ajax toolkit with server-side controls such as UpdatePanel).

ASP.NET MVC is more basic and therefore more work. You handle Ajax calls on the client side using a library such as jQuery, and on the server side you implement a controller with Ajax methods.

Have a look at http://sweettam.blogspot.com/2011/06/aspnet-mvc-3-ajax-part-i.html.